# Configure geoserver to ignore format_options

Tags: geoserver

I'm using Geoserver 2.8.1. Is it possible to configure the server to ignore certain format_options passed to Geoserver's WMS service?

Comment: You mean these http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wms/vendor.html? Probably not at the moment but mention one that you would like to be disabled as an example so it is easier check what could be done with the security tools.

Comment: for example kmscore.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible. You will have to write your own servlet filter or spring dispatcher equivalent to wipe them out of the request.